# From an ERD, how to determine the order to create tables using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, erd

I know that when creating tables I am supposed to create parents before children. Currently I have `Customers` being created first, followed by `Inventory`, `Salesperson`, `Orderitems` then `Orders`.

The tables are created, however when I attempt to fill the tables in that order, only the `Customer` and `Inventory` tables are filled.

Am I creating these tables in the wrong order, or filling them in the wrong order? Or both?

See below for the ERD:

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "I attempt to fill the tables in that order". Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: **[edit]** your question and ad the code that "fills" the tables. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: `Orders` need to be populated before `Orderitems`